# iOS 14 not letting Flutter apps (still in dev) to launch from the home screen compared to Building/Running from the IDE

Tags: ios, iphone, android-studio, flutter, ios14

I've been developing a news app with Flutter and when I build and run it through Android Studio it launches fine, but when I try to launch the app by clicking on it on the home screen, it says "in iOS 14+, debug mode flutter apps can only be launched from Flutter tooling,IDEs ....."(Screenshot attatched). Can someone tell me as to how to get around this?
[image]

Comment: FYI, the screenshot is not attached.

Comment: Shoot I must’ve forgot....just did it now lmao

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known issue of Flutter on iOS 14 for apps in debug mode, see this article on the [Flutter website](http://in%20iOS%2014+,%20debug%20mode%20flutter%20apps%20can%20only%20be%20launched%20from%20Flutter%20tooling), and this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60657#issuecomment-688478590). So for the time being, I believe your main workarounds are the following:

- Always run the app from the host PC (using `flutter run`, IDE debug, etc.)
- Build a release version of your app (instead of debug) and use that on your device, e.g. use `flutter run --release`
- Use a device with iOS 13 or older
- Use a simulator

Comment: Hi Anis, could you explain option 2 (flutter run) a bit further?!

Comment: @w461 Basically step 2 is: Open a terminal on your project directory, and write the command `flutter run --release`. Didn't test myself if that option fixes the issue, I simply found it in the linked pages.

Comment: simulator fixed for my issue

Comment: `flutter run --release` worked like a charm

Answer (score 32):

**If you want to use the app without being connected via usb**

1. Open the ios folder on Xcode
2. Make sure your device is connected
3. Select *Product* from the menu bar -> *Scheme* -> Edit Scheme

   Or simply use the shortcut: <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd>

[Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE0rk.png)

4. Change the build configure to *Release*
5. Run the app from Xcode
6. Disconnect your device and you're good to go!

Comment: Worked like a charm on iOS 16.